# Is there a way to dynamically reload and then reuse dll and all its classes when app is running?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

My target is below scenario:

- I started application (Win32)
- The application uses a set of classes from some .NET Class library.
- I change some code in this .NET Class library, compile new dll
- In my running application i destruct all the objects from this library and reload it.
- My app is still running and all code changes are done!

I suppose that Spiring.NET (or similar framework) provides such functionality and need Your help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can not unload an assembly once you loaded it. You can however unload an [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). So the way this is done in .NET is to load that assembly in a seprate `AppDomain` that later can be unloaded again.
[Here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/steve_holstad/archive/2007/06/28/3212.aspx) is a simple example how to do it.

However, this approach has the downside that the objects you want to call from the other assembly must derive from [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) Alternatively you could use the [System.Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.aspx) framework.